Rails - I'm working on a Ruby on Rails app and I'm running into a challenge regarding n+1 queries, and STI models
I'm working on a Ruby on Rails app and I'm running into a challenge regarding n+1 queries, and STI models.
I have the following models
class ResourceAssigment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :resource
    belongs_to :assigned_to, polymorphic: true
end

class Resource < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :resource_assigments
end

class VideoLinkResource < Resource
end

class LinkResource < Resource
end

class ScormCloudResource < Resource
  belongs_to :scorm_cloud_course

  validates_presence_of :scorm_cloud_course
end

class FileResource < Resource
  has_one_attached :file

  validates_presence_of :file
end

I'm trying to load all ResourceAssigments like so:
ResourceAssignment.includes(:assigned_to)
However, I'm getting a bullet warning for n+1 query:
user: root USE eager loading detected ResourceAssignment => [:resource] Add to your query: .includes([:resource])

The challenge is that Resource is a STI. When I add .includes([:resource]) then the warning says:
user: root USE eager loading detected FileResource => [:file_attachment] Add to your query: .includes([:file_attachment])
user: root USE eager loading detected ScormCloudResource => [:scorm_cloud_course] Add to your query: .includes([:scorm_cloud_course])

And when I try to include the other resources I run into all sort of issues like Association named 'link_resources' was not found on FileResource
Ideally I would like to have a scope in ResourceAssigment which would include / pre-load all resources.
Any ideas?

Have you taken a look at this?
